# Django unicode method doesn't work

Tags: django, unicode, django-models

When I define a class in my model part, I write a `__unicode__` method. But it still shows the class name + object form. Like, Publisher object

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name
```

Comment: What's the error are you getting? Everything seems fine.

Comment: Where do you see this "classname + object" form model representation?

Comment: Yeah, where do you see this: in the admin interface or in the shell?

Comment: In the Browser (I use chrome). running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin@sachitad

Comment: In general, I will present like "O'relly" and so on. But it presents just "Publisher object"@alecxe

Comment: If you are not in development server, make sure the model .pyc file has been refreshed.

Comment: also try overriding `__str__`

Comment: The function that returns this "classname + object" is `__repr__`. Try overriding that.

Comment: Using the __str__ solved the problem. But I am not sure, the Django's version is 1.5, on the webpage and the document of django, they all said should use __unicode__. I am confused@husbas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are using Python 3+ then You should use the `str` type and `__str__` function, as there are no `unicode` type. Probably Django documentation is outdated here.

I'm not really sure about this, so above paragraph may be also a total nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

As @Python Fanboy said, it might be because you're running python3:
[See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/#s-str-and-unicode-methods)

Django only started supporting py3 quite recently, so most of the old docs probably needs some updating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same tutorial and also encountered this error about incorrect output (no real effect after adding **unicode**() methods to code). 
**In my case the problem was incorrect indentation of _*unicode*_() method.** I didn't notice this at first because there were no errors in console after reentering the shell (python manage.py shell). After careful retyping the Publisher class everything works fine.